# Number axis with interval symbols

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, plot

I am looking for something like this:

[image: axis]

I have tried using the pgfplots package, but I cannot figure out how to add the brackets or the colors

Comment: What you try so far? Similar question I see on the site ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on one of the similar previous answer (which I temporary can't find):

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (-3,0) -- (3,0);
  \draw (0,2pt) -- (0,-2pt) node[below=2mm] {$0$};
  \draw[{Bracket[width=4mm]}-{Bracket[width=4mm]}] 
    (-2,0) node[below=2mm] {$-1$} -- ( 2,0) node[below=2mm] {$ 1$};
  \draw[{Parenthesis[width=4mm]}-{Parenthesis[width=4mm]}]
    (-1,0) node[below=2mm] {$-\frac{1}{2}$} -- (1,0) node[below=2mm] {$ \frac{1}{2}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!